# SharpDX: Позиция курсора сбивается при зуммировании в точку

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d, sharpdx

**SharpDX 2.6**

При зуммировании или изменении размера окна изменяю *RenderTarget* через свойство *Transform*. В результате "сбивается" определение местоположения курсора мыши.

[image: Наведение на элемент Thirty]
На скрине - наведение на элемент Thirty.

Если кто знает, как исправить этот неприятный эффект, буду очень благодарен за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, проблема решена. Завёл дополнительное поле/свойство для "глобальной" позиции *GlobalXY*. При зуммировании раньше я использовал только *renderTarget.Transform()*, сейчас же обрабатывается также *OnScroll*. Это позволяет при пересчете учитывать и *zoom*, и отступы.